# JavaScript replace in string using Regex based on json Array

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I need to replace all with in `{}` and the `{}` themselves with data I have in a JSON array using a regex and it needs to be in case-sensitive.

The number of `{}`s may change depending on the page.

```
s ="<address><div>{Name}</div><div>{Address1}</div><div>{Address2}</div><div>{ZipCode} {City}</div><div>{State}</div><div>{Country}</div><div>{ContactName}</div></address>"

"DeliveryAddress":
        {
            "Id":5637169131,
            "Name":"some name",
            "Name2":null,
            "Address":"Somewhere street 12",
            "Address2":null,
            "City":"Heven",
            "ZipCode":"1111",
            "State":"FL",
                        "Country":"US",
            "VatNo":null,
            "ContactRecId":"Receiving Department",
            "ContactName":null,
            "ContactPhone":null,
            "ContactEmail":null,
            "DefaultShopDeliveryAddress":false,
            "DefaultServiceDeliveryAddress":false,
            "IsOneTime":false,
            "CaptureId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        },
```

When done i need to have the matching element in my json array replace the matching {tag}

Example

```
<address><div>some name</div><div>Somewhere street 12</div><div></div><div>1111 Heaven</div><div>FL</div><div>US</div><div></div></address>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
s ="<address><div>{Name}</div><div>{Address1}</div><div>{Address2}</div><div>{ZipCode} {City}</div><div>{State}</div><div>{Country}</div><div>{ContactName}</div></address>"
DeliveryAddress = {
            "Id":5637169131,
            "Name":"some name",
            "Name2":null,
            "Address1":"Somewhere street 12",
            "Address2":null,
            "City":"Heven",
            "ZipCode":"1111",
            "State":"FL",
            "Country":"US",
            "VatNo":null,
            "ContactRecId":"Receiving Department",
            "ContactName":null,
            "ContactPhone":null,
            "ContactEmail":null,
            "DefaultShopDeliveryAddress":false,
            "DefaultServiceDeliveryAddress":false,
            "IsOneTime":false,
            "CaptureId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        };

for (var key in DeliveryAddress) {
  var r = new RegExp('{' + key + '}', "i");
  s = s.replace(r, DeliveryAddress[key]);
}
console.log(s);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<address><div>some name</div><div>Somewhere street 12</div><div></div><div>1111 Heaven</div><div>FL</div><div>US</div><div></div></address>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.replace with global and multiline flags set:

```
function s_fill(s, dict) {
    for (var n in dict) {
        var re = new RegExp('{' + n + '}', 'gm');
        s = s.replace(re, dict[n]);
    }
    return s;
}
```